# What is the difference between ROOT_QUERY and $ROOT_QUERY in Apollo In-memory Cache?

Tags: apollo-client

In my Apollo In-memory Cache, some fields have a prefix of `$ROOT_QUERY` while others just have `ROOT_QUERY`. I can't seem to crack what the difference is, both from the behavior of my cache, the docs, or the code.